# How to inherit Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have several Windows services in my project, with a lot of common code. I want to create a base service. First part is simple - I create this class:

```
public abstract class MyServiceBase : ServiceBase
{
    protected abstract override void OnStart(string[] args);
}
```

But what can I do with `ProjectInstaller`? MSDN says that each service is going to have a `ProjectInstaller` and included `ServiceInstaller` component.

How can I create these in the base class and customize in derived services?

Comment: I would recommend looking at [Topshelf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TopShelf) - it is a much nicer way to develop services, and handles installation for you - _"By referencing Topshelf, your console application *becomes* a service installer"_ - but each service will need to be in a separate project, whichever way you develop them.

Comment: I do not expect that there is much benefit in sharing the installers. For each service you will have to specify a separate name, description and perhaps dependencies. So I would recommend to not use the base class for this. Also: if these services are so similar it might be worth it to turn them into one service. In general I try to have one deliverable per solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) unless you want to work in the legacy way. It creates a `console` `.exe` that can be installed `servicename.exe install` and uninstalled `servicename.exe uninstall` with these commands.